# How OpenAPI Generator .openapi-generator-ignore works on openapi-generator-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I want that openapi-generator-maven-plugin do not generates `${openapi-generator.base-package}/OpenApiGeneratorApplicationTests.java`.

I'm trying correctly use .openapi-generator-ignore feature.

My currently maven plugin configuration can be viewed on this [repository](https://github.com/kinlhpsoftwareinc/moname/blob/develop/pom.xml).

Answer (score 6):

After hitting my head a lot *(Brazilian expression for trying several times)*, I found a mechanism provided by the plugin itself.

It consists of two steps:

1. Create `${project.baseDir}/.openapi-generator-ignore` defining the paths to be ignored:

```
# ${project.baseDir}/.openapi-generator-ignore

# https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/customization.md#ignore-file-format
#
# Use this file to prevent files from being overwritten by the generator.
# The patterns follow closely to .gitignore or .dockerignore.

**/OpenApiGeneratorApplicationTests.java
```

2. Define in the plugin configuration (`<ignoreFileOverride>`) the file that defines the path to be ignored (`.openapi-generator-ignore`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.kinlhp</groupId>
    <artifactId>moname-build</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>Project to money me with no name [build].</description>
    <url>https://moname.kinlhp.com</url>
    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}</main.basedir>
        <maven.compiler.release>${java.version}</maven.compiler.release>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <openapi-generator.base-package>com.kinlhp.moname.commons.api.oas</openapi-generator.base-package>
        <openapi-generator.input-spec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi/specification.yaml</openapi-generator.input-spec>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <!-- dependency versions -->
        <revision>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</revision>
        <!-- # third party # -->
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <openapi-generator-maven-plugin.version>6.6.0</openapi-generator-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!-- # third party # -->
                <!-- openapitools -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${openapi-generator-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>openapi-generator</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- README#openapi-generator-spring-metadata -->
                                <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                                <!-- README#openapi-generator-spring-config-options -->
                                <apiPackage>${openapi-generator.base-package}.endpoint</apiPackage>
                                <artifactId>moname-commons-api-oas</artifactId>
                                <artifactVersion>${revision}</artifactVersion>
                                <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                                <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                <ignoreFileOverride>.openapi-generator-ignore</ignoreFileOverride>
                                <inputSpec>${openapi-generator.input-spec}</inputSpec>
                                <invokerPackage>${openapi-generator.base-package}.invoker</invokerPackage>
                                <modelNameSuffix>DTO</modelNameSuffix>
                                <modelPackage>${openapi-generator.base-package}.payload</modelPackage>
                                <configOptions>
                                    <!-- README#openapi-generator-spring-metadata -->
                                    <generatorLanguage>Java</generatorLanguage>
                                    <generatorType>SERVER</generatorType>
                                    <!-- README#openapi-generator-spring-config-options -->
                                    <artifactDescription>Project to money me with no name [commons-api-oas].</artifactDescription>
                                    <artifactUrl>${project.url}</artifactUrl>
                                    <basePackage>${openapi-generator.base-package}</basePackage>
                                    <bigDecimalAsString>true</bigDecimalAsString>
                                    <booleanGetterPrefix>is</booleanGetterPrefix>
                                    <configPackage>${openapi-generator.base-package}.configuration</configPackage>
                                    <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                                    <developerEmail>lhp.kin@gmail.com</developerEmail>
                                    <developerName>Luis Henrique Pereira</developerName>
                                    <developerOrganization>${project.organization.name}</developerOrganization>
                                    <developerOrganizationUrl>${project.organization.url}</developerOrganizationUrl>
                                    <licenseName>MIT License</licenseName>
                                    <licenseUrl>https://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php</licenseUrl>
                                    <parentArtifactId>moname-commons</parentArtifactId>
                                    <parentGroupId>${project.parent.groupId}</parentGroupId>
                                    <parentVersion>${revision}</parentVersion>
                                    <performBeanValidation>true</performBeanValidation>
                                    <scmConnection>${project.scm.connection}</scmConnection>
                                    <scmDeveloperConnection>${project.scm.developerConnection}</scmDeveloperConnection>
                                    <scmUrl>${project.scm.url}</scmUrl>
                                    <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                                    <title>Project to money me with no name [commons-api-oas].</title>
                                    <unhandledException>true</unhandledException>
                                    <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
                                    <useSpringController>true</useSpringController>
                                </configOptions>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

As result, the ignore behavior can be seen by the log:

```bash
./mvn --batch-mode --define skipTests --no-transfer-progress --threads 1C --update-snapshots clean package
```

```
...
[INFO] --- openapi-generator:6.6.0:generate (default-generate) @ moname-addressing-api ---
[INFO] Generating with dryRun=false
[INFO] OpenAPI Generator: spring (server)
[INFO] Generator 'spring' is considered stable.
[INFO] ----------------------------------
[INFO] Environment variable JAVA_POST_PROCESS_FILE not defined so the Java code may not be properly formatted. To define it, try 'export JAVA_POST_PROCESS_FILE="/usr/local/bin/clang-format -i"' (Linux/Mac)
[INFO] NOTE: To enable file post-processing, 'enablePostProcessFile' must be set to `true` (--enable-post-process-file for CLI).
[INFO] Processing operation getCountries
...
[INFO] Ignored /home/kin/projects/moname/moname-addressing/moname-addressing-api/target/generated-sources/openapi/src/test/java/com/kinlhp/moname/addressing/api/oas/OpenApiGeneratorApplicationTests.java (Ignored by rule in ignore file.)
...
################################################################################
# Thanks for using OpenAPI Generator.                                          #
# Please consider donation to help us maintain this project                  #
# https://opencollective.com/openapi_generator/donate                          #
################################################################################
...
```

The complete code can be seen on this [repository](https://github.com/kinlhpsoftwareinc/moname/blob/develop/pom.xml).